# "Track Event" is seen in Console (GA Debug) but network request isn't seen in Network Panel

Tags: google-analytics

I am confused with the track event issue.

```
//_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Cat', 'Act', 'Label', 1.1]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/new']);
```

This is working, I can see this in GA Debugger:

```
_gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]":  ga_debug.js:18
Track Pageview ga_debug.js:18
Tracking beacon sent!
```

And I can see the __utm.gif request in Network Panel.

But when I changed the code to :

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Cat', 'Act', 'Label', 1.1]);
//_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/new']);
```

Here is the output in console from GA debugger:

_gaq.push processing "_trackEvent" for args: "[Cat,Act,Label,1]":  ga_debug.js:18
Track Event

But I never see a 'Tracking beacon sent!'. And I cannot see a __utm.gif request in Network Panel. After waiting for days, I did not see any records in the GA Report. So I am very sure it's never sent.

Am I doing anything wrong in this case? Thanks very much for any kind of help!

UPDATE:

I finally tested a couple of times and knew:

The value passed to Ga MUST BE AN INT type. So 1.1 is not working but 1 is working.

I think GA Debugger should add a warning and output it in the console :)

Comment: You should post an answer with the answer about the INT type; otherwise, this question appears as if it is unanswered and won't help others solve the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

I finally tested a couple of times and knew:

The value passed to Ga MUST BE AN **INT** type. So 1.1 is not working but 1 is working.

I think GA Debugger should add a warning and output it in the console :)

Answer (score 0):

You could check the tag implementation using the chrome extension called [Trackie](https://github.com/pualien/Trackie)