# I don't know why my tracking beacon isn't being sent as I debug my Google Analytics

Tags: debugging, google-analytics

I'm having the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149414/track-event-is-seen-in-console-ga-debug-but-network-request-isnt-seen-in-ne), but I am using an INT value, and I don't know why it's not working.

Here's what the source code looks like on the page:

```
<a href="#" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Headline click', 'HeadlineLabel', '1', 0, false]);">This is a headline link</a>
```

And this is what I'm getting in the console while using the Google Analytics debugger chrome extension (substituting X's in places for privacy):

```
_gaq.push processing "_setDomainName" for args: "[XXXXXXXXX.XX]": 
ga_debug.js:24 _gaq.push processing "_setAccount" for args: "[UA-XXXXXXXX-X]": 
ga_debug.js:24 _gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]": 
ga_debug.js:24 Track Pageview
ga_debug.js:24 Found UA client id
ga_debug.js:24 _gaq.push processing "_setAccount" for args: "[UA-XXXXXXXX-X]": 
ga_debug.js:24 _gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]": 
ga_debug.js:24 Track Pageview
ga_debug.js:24 _gaq.push processing "_setAccount" for args: "[UA-XXXXXXXX-X]": 
ga_debug.js:24 _gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]": 
ga_debug.js:24 Track Pageview
```

The above looks as intended based on the Tag Manager's code provided by my client. Then I click on a link to test its event tracking.

```
ga_debug.js:24 _gaq.push processing "_trackEvent" for args: "[Headline click,HeadlineLabel,1,0,false]": 
ga_debug.js:24 Track Event
```

The client sent along a picture of the debugger of what it's supposed to say if it's working correctly. In their version, there is only one line, instead of two, and it should say "Tracking Beacon Sent!"

So why is there no "Tracking Beacon Sent!"? Can someone point out my mistake, please? I thought maybe GA updated their extension and changed the output message, but I don't know where that information would be. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please check in your real-time reports, immediately after triggering the event, to see if the hit is sent. I've verified that your onclick code is working and I can see the event hit in my RT reporting. Also, I also did not see a "Tracking beacon sent" message, but that is expected.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but where do I find the real-time reports? I'm relatively new with the chrome extension and my knowledge of GA is limited. Is that not the same as what it outputs to my browser console?

And why do you say it expected to not see a "Tracking Beacon Sent!" message? My issue is that I am expecting to see it, and I'm not getting it.

Comment: The Real-Time report would be in your Google Analytics account. When you log in to GA, go to Reporting, and then select Real-Time in the left column, and then Events. If your event successfully fires, then you should see it in the Real-time report. If you do see it, then everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738815/google-analytics-gif-request-not-sent). With my limited knowledge of Google Analytics, I didn't know to look for the __utm.gif request in my Network panel. Sure enough, it wasn't being requested either.

The site I'm working on is currently being hosted on an extranet. While it wasn't a localhost or intranet site, it seems like this is an issue with extranet sites as well.

Whoever added the pageview code in the head originally included a domain name. Replacing it with 'none' worked for me.

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', "none"]);
```